# saslpasswd2 create a password programmatically

Tags: sasl

I need to create a script to set a sasldb password programmatically for different users:

```
#!/bin/bash
passwd=test
saslpasswd -c -u domain.org user0
```

How can I pass the `$passwd` variable to this script?

The Only option about password is this:

> *`-p Pipe mode` - saslpasswd2 will neither prompt for the password nor verify that it was entered correctly. This is the default when standard input is not a terminal.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
echo test | saslpasswd -p -c -u domain.org user0
```